# Back lighted mirror

Tags: lighting, bathroom, light-fixture, mirror, vanity

I would like to know how I could get a mirror like this:

[image]

Does it need to be custom made If it need to be custom made, by who?

Glass store or light store?

thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure that is not just a light bar on the front side of the glass?

Answer (score 2):

The source depends a lot on how the surface of the lighted mirror border is created. If the same sheet of glass forms the mirror and the lighted border area then this is certainly a specially made glass. Such glass would have the mirror finish applied across the back with the border edges chemically etched to create a frosted glass behind which the back light is placed. Seems to me that producing such thing would be prohibitively expensive even to the extent that I doubt that you would find a manufacturer producing a product configured like that.

It is far more likely that the back lighted border is a produced as long narrow strips of frosted glass or a plastic material that is a translucent white color. Since the mirror itself does not transmit light from the back it would be quite likely that the border material is wider than the visible portion and the mirror is installed in front of the border material. If the border material and the mirror had the same thermal expansion characteristics it is possible that the border could even be bonded to the rear edge of the mirror.

The back light looks to me like it is multiple strips of white LEDs affixed to the wall behind the border material.

So I would conclude that it would be an entirely possible DIY project to produce such a structure by installing the LED strips, and wiring to power them, then install a wooden frame on the wall that was a bit smaller in dimensions than the mirror glass. Next the border strips would be mounted from the wall/ceiling/floor edges over the LED strips and affixed to the wooden frame. Plastic border material would be far more practical as it could be mounted with flat head screws into the wooden frame. Finally the mirror would be placed in front of the wooden frame to hide it and cover the mount points of the border material.

One would hope that the LED strips have a long life as it would be quite the undertaking to disassemble the whole thing to replace them.

Another note. Although it is built to look like the mirror and back lighted borders are fully extending behind the vanity it seems highly unlikely to be the case. Repair would be like a full bathroom remodel if the vanity had to be removed to get behind the mirror.

Comment: I've seen this done with fluorescents, but of course you then have to make more provision for replacing tubes. LED would be better now that it's available. As the photo suggests, this setup is more common in hotels than homes.

Comment: +1 for the comment about hotels. Could also apply to other types of high buck public places. Consider also that nearly useless artsy sink.